# На локальном и на хостинге "глобально" выводит разный формат десятичного числа

Tags: laravel, float

На локалке и на хостинге "глобально" выводит разный формат десятичного числа, в том числе при использовании `print_r()`.

[image: разный формат отображения]

Нужно чтобы как на локалке: выводило точку как символ разделения целых и дробных чисел.

Возможно что-то в Laravel, так как пробовал вывести дробное число в `\public\index.php` и вывело как надо с точкой, в отличии от вывода в шаблонах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина проблемы: на локальной машине и на хостинге установлены разные [локали](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setlocale.php). Это в том числе влияет и на формат вывода чисел.

Решение: установите локаль в коде, поскольку иначе PHP возьмет ее из настроек системы, в которой выполняется. Пример:

```php
    // Вставьте этот код, например, в bootstrap/app.php
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, config('app.locale'));
```

(не забудьте прописать нужную локаль в config/app.php)

или просто

```php
    // Вставьте этот код, например, в bootstrap/app.php или контроллер
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

[О локалях в Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization) (отличается от локалей PHP потому как используется только для перевода контента, для правильного форматирования требуется доработка напильником или сторонний пакет)

Comment: Спасибо, ответ помог!