# Глобально убрать нули после точки / запятой PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php7

Столкнулся с проблемой что на сервере числа(double) отображаются с нулями, а локально без, как собственно и требуется.

Можно ли убрать их глобально, через конфиг php или web-сервера, или почему так происходит?

Пример кода:

```
<input type="text" name="sum" value="{{ $order->invoice->sum }}"//Blade

<input type="text" name="sum" value="<?php echo e($order->invoice->sum); ?>"
```

Пример вывода на сервере:

[image: сервер]

локально:

[image: локально]

Данные берутся из базы MySQL. Используется php 7.1 ,Laravel 5.2

Comment: На сервере как вы выводите числа? Через `echo`?

Comment: А что значит "на сервере" и "локально"?

Comment: @СергейМишин , "локально" имеется в виду на локальном сервере разработки(в данном случае Vagrant Laravel Homestead) , "на сервере"  имеется в виду на хостинге, извиняюсь за непонятность изъяснения.

Comment: @potiev в примере кода показано. Это синтаксис шаблонизатора Blade который потом преобразует это в 
<input type="text" name="sum" value="<?php echo e($order->invoice->sum); ?>"

Comment: Смежный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1007134/256824

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = preg_replace('#.00#', '', $sum);
```

или

```
 $sum = str_replace(['.00',',00'], '', $sum);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Данный вариант подходит для "локальной" правки, а в данном случае вопрос стоит о глобальном изменении.